# JavaScript to find the start and end column index of cells in tables with merged columns and rows

Tags: javascript, html

Consider this table:

http://jsbin.com/esikac/1/edit

Note how each cell has a value pair like "x-y", x is the start column index and y is the end column index (where column in this case would be the line between columns instead of the column itself, starting at zero). Hope this makes sense.

What I need is some javascript that will take a cell (a td element) and give me it's start and end column index just as in my sample table. So, say I have a function `getColumnBounds` that takes a `td` element as a parameter. If I call it and pass the `td` on the top right of my table, it'll give me "3-5" (of course not by reading the text inside but by figuring it out).

This is what I have so far, but if fails as soon as I add merged rows:

```
function getColumnBounds(td) {

    function colSpan(col) {
        return parseInt((col && col.nodeType == 1 && element.nodeName.match(/t[dh]/i)) ? (col.getAttribute("colSpan") || 1) : 0);
    }

    function endIndex(element) {
        var colPos = colSpan(element);

        while(element) {
            element = element.previousSibling;
            colPos += colSpan(element);
        }

        return colPos;
    }

    var startIndex = endIndex(td.previousSibling);
    var endIndex = endIndex(td);
    return ("" + startIndex + "-" + endIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First a comment.

For traversal of table cells, consider taking advantage of the [rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46975887), [rowIndex](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67347567), [cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-67349879) and [cellIndex](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-80748363) properties to navigate rather than siblings (since siblings may be text nodes, not elements), e.g.:

```
function getCellNext(cell) {
  return cell.parentNode.cells[cell.cellIndex + 1] || null;
}
```

Most DOM methods return `null` if they can't find a suitable node to return. If the function returns `null`, then *cell* is the last cell in the row. Similar strategies can be used to get the previous cell, or the one above or below, e.g.

```
function getCellAbove(cell) {
  var row = cell.parentNode;
  var table = row.parentNode.parentNode; // may use tableSection instead
  var rowAbove = table.rows[row.rowIndex - 1];
  return rowAbove? row.cells[cell.cellIndex] : null;
}
```

Using a single listener on the table, the following returns the column and row range for a particular cell:

```
// Get the cell and row range of a particular cell
function getCellRange(cell) {
  var colRange = cell.cellIndex + '-' + (cell.cellIndex + cell.colSpan - 1);
  var row = cell.parentNode;
  var rowRange = row.rowIndex + '-' + (row.rowIndex + cell.rowSpan - 1);
  return [colRange, rowRange];
}

// Helper functions
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  while (el && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != tagName) {
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return el || null;
}

// Call getCellRange from an event
function showCellRange(e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var cell = upTo(target, 'td');
  return cell? getCellRange(cell) : null;
}
```

And the listener (and table) is:

```
  <table onclick="alert(showCellRange(event));">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">0-2
    <td rowspan="2">2-3
    <td colspan="2">3-5
  <tr>
    <td>0-1
    <td>1-2
    <td>3-4
    <td>4-5
  <tr>
    <td>0-1
    <td colspan="2">1-3
    <td>3-4
    <td>4-5
  <tr>
    <td>0-1
    <td colspan="3">1-4
    <td>4-5
  <tr>
    <td>0-1
    <td>1-2
    <td colspan="2">2-4
    <td>4-5
</table>
```

I think your ranges are incorrect. If the first cell has a colspan of 2, then its range is 0-1 not 0-2.

Also, since *rowSpan*, *rowIndex*, *cellSpan* and *cellIndex* are all type Number, there is no need for *parseInt*. Nor do I understand why you've included jQuery in the jsbin code.